# How to prevent implicit initialization in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi`s record and I wrote a constructor for it

```
TNullableDateTime = record
  IsNull: Boolean;
  Value: TDateTime;
  constructor Create(IsNull: Boolean; Value: TDateTime)
end;
```

the problem is that I want to prevent creating this type of record implicitly like:

```
SomeNullableDateTime: TNullableDateTime;
SomeNullableDateTime.IsNull:= True;
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at [A "Nullable" Post by Allen Bauer](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/a-andquotnullableandquot-post-38869) There you will find solution for your problem - and that is creating nullable record.

Comment: I suggest to use [Spring4D Nullable<T>](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/src/6ce84d716e33be33c2914319ec7d143d5fb2adc4/Source/Base/Spring.pas?at=master#Spring.pas-308)

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done. If you want to force the members to be initialized by the use of the constructor, you need a reference type (a class).

Comment: i see... i wanted to avoid this kind of overhead.

Comment: In this scenario I would suggest you ignore any advice to add managed types to your type. As Uwe suggests for instance. Doing so just leaves you with a type full of distraction. My suggestion is that you make sure that you always initialize your types. Onus back to the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

The only what you can do: make the member data private like

```
TNullableDateTime = record
 private
  IsNull: Boolean;
  Value: TDateTime;
 public
  constructor Create(IsNull: Boolean; Value: TDateTime);
  function getValue : TDateTime;
  function getIsNull : boolean;
end;
```

So you have to add setter and getters for your type. 
You can also do read only properties

Comment: This doesn't force the user to call the constructor and the values are not initialized

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right, the only thing is, you can prevent the use as classical record

Comment: But what you propose doesn't force initialization. Nothing here changes behaviour of code in question.

Answer (score 2):

As David mentioned, you cannot force the use of *Create* at compile time (even not with classes), but you can raise an exception at run time when someone touches the properties without calling *Create* before. This code changes the fields to properties and makes use of the fact, that string fields inside records are initialized to an empty string:

```
type
  TNullableDateTime = record
  private
    FIsNull: Boolean;
    FSentinel: string;
    FValue: TDateTime;
    procedure CheckSentinel;
    function GetIsNull: Boolean;
    function GetValue: TDateTime;
    procedure SetIsNull(const AValue: Boolean);
    procedure SetValue(const AValue: TDateTime);
  public
    constructor Create(AIsNull: Boolean; const AValue: TDateTime);
    property IsNull: Boolean read GetIsNull write SetIsNull;
    property Value: TDateTime read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

constructor TNullableDateTime.Create(AIsNull: Boolean; const AValue: TDateTime);
begin
  FSentinel := '*';
  FValue := AValue;
  FIsNull := AIsNull;
end;

procedure TNullableDateTime.CheckSentinel;
begin
  if FSentinel = '' then
    raise Exception.Create('please use TNullableDateTime.Create!');
end;

function TNullableDateTime.GetIsNull: Boolean;
begin
  CheckSentinel;
  Result := FIsNull;
end;

function TNullableDateTime.GetValue: TDateTime;
begin
  CheckSentinel;
  Result := FValue;
end;

procedure TNullableDateTime.SetIsNull(const AValue: Boolean);
begin
  CheckSentinel;
  FIsNull := AValue;
end;

procedure TNullableDateTime.SetValue(const AValue: TDateTime);
begin
  CheckSentinel;
  FValue := AValue;
end;
```